# Web API 2 parameter binding missing some values

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am creating an Web API 2 application and a separate MVC client as there will be mobile apps also accessing the Web API 2 application.

In the Web API 2 the RegisterBindingModel class is

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

In the client the RegisterBinderModel class is

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC client I am trying to register a new user.

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.Email);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.Password);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.ConfirmPassword);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(url);

            HttpClient test = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage result2= await  test.PostAsJsonAsync(url, user);
```

The register post method is

```
    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.Email);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.Password); // Is null?
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.ConfirmPassword); //Is null?

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) // Is of course false
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that only the email value is bound in the Web API register method. The  password and confirmpassword values are null in the bound parameter of the my post method. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's because you are posting an `ApplicationUser` which only has an `Email` property set. Try posting the `model` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are posting `user` which an `ApplicationUser` & only has its `Email` property set:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
HttpClient test = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage result2 = await test.PostAsJsonAsync(url, user);
```

Try posting the `model` instead.

```
HttpResponseMessage result2 = await test.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
```

Comment: I felt like deleting this stupid question as it's not really helpful to anyone else except for others who also need more sleep...

Comment: @user3140169 haha. Never delete the truth, lest you forget it.